# Java Lines Confusion

Tags: java

I am having a problem with my java code. I'm trying to make it so the top left quadrant produces a set number of lines input by a user through JOption Pane which are in random colors and in random positions. The programs builds successfully but it does not produce the number of lines the user input, nor does it set a random color (This it at the very bottom of my code). Can someone please explain how to fix this problem? Thanks very much.
Edit: fixed the curve braces but still will not work.
Edit: Everything works now except the random colors

```
import javax.swing.*;   //for JFrame
import java.awt.*;      //for Graphics and Container
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

// other import statements here


public class RandomGraphics
{
    // constants are used to draw the grid, and for you to put shapes in the grid
    public static final int MIDX = 400;
    public static final int MIDY = 300;
    public static final int MAXX = 799;
    public static final int MAXY = 599;
    public static final int COLOR = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

    // make another constant for the color value that will
    // be used to generate a random color

    public static void main( String[] args )throws InterruptedException
    {
        //*** This next section sets up the graphics window.
        //*** You are not required to understand it
        Container contentPane;
        Graphics g;
        JFrame win = new JFrame("Random Graphics");
        win.setSize(825,650);
        win.setLocation(0,0);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = win.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
        g = contentPane.getGraphics();
        Thread.sleep(50);
        //*** done setting up graphics window


        // Draws Grid - DO NOT CHANGE
        // After you use JOptionPane to get the number of lines, you can move this
        // section of code to just after that, so the lines will not disappear
        g.drawRect(0,0,MAXX+1,MAXY+1);
        g.drawLine(0,MIDY,MAXX,MIDY); // horizontal line
        g.drawLine(MIDX,0,MIDX,MAXY); // vertical line


        // Create Random object
        Random r = new Random();



        // Top left quadrant:


        // Use a JOptionPane to ask the user to enter the number of lines 1 to 100.
        int count = 0;
        do
        {

            String morelines = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number of lines between 1 to 100");
            count = Integer.parseInt(morelines);
        }
        while(count > 100 || count < 1);


        for(int i = 1; i >= count; i++)
{
                g.setColor(new Color (r.nextInt(COLOR), r.nextInt(COLOR), r.nextInt(COLOR)));
                g.drawLine(r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY), r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY));
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g = contentPane.getGraphics();
```

`Graphics` objects are not persistent, the programmer needs to draw the GUI to them when asked to do so.  For tips, see the [Performing Custom Painting Lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) of the tutorial.

---

Beside the 'always include curly braces around loops advice', note..

```
for(int i = 1; i >= count; i++)
```

Should be..

```
for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
```

But don't ignore the advice about custom painting.  The app. will not render reliably until that is fixed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice I will try to do that, however setting random colors for the lines is not working so I am trying to fix that

Comment: Also your statement works but I am confused, isn't i always less than count so it will only run once?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i = 1; i >= count; i++)
        g.setColor(new Color (r.nextInt(COLOR), r.nextInt(COLOR), r.nextInt(COLOR)));
        g.drawLine(r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY), r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY));
```

Looking at your indenting, it looks like you want `g.setColor(...)` and `g.drawLine(...)` to be inside your for loop. You need to enclose them in curly braces `{}`, otherwise only the statement immediately following your for loop will be inside the loop.

Comment: This is a fantastic reason to just *always* use curly braces, even for one line bodies.  That way, you just never have to even think about whether what you're doing is correct.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I set curly braces, but now I get absolutely nothing when I input and run the program :(